# UNEXPECTED_FRAME - expected content header for class 60, got non content header frame instead

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

What I am doing is, imagine that you have several workflows that need to execute. These workflows have tasks, and the target of the tasks are different hosts.
The fastest way to do this is running every workflow inside a process, and run them in parallel.

I am trying to run python multiprocessing to execute a remote function that I call with the help of celery. My program runs  ok if I just run one process. But when I run more than one process, I get the error below. As far as I got, the issue is with concurrent publishing on the same channel. Channels should not be shared between threads/etc.

How I can make Celery to resolve this? Is is a parameter that I should launch with 'celeryd' command, or I need to do it in my python program?

```
    Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "testHello.py", line 16, in test_hello_aux
    print output.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 169, in get
    no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 155, in wait_for
    on_interval=on_interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 229, in consume
    no_ack=no_ack, accept=self.accept) as consumer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 359, in __init__
    self.revive(self.channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 371, in revive
    self.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 381, in declare
    queue.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 505, in declare
    self.queue_declare(nowait, passive=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 531, in queue_declare
    nowait=nowait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1254, in queue_declare
    self._send_method((50, 10), args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 56, in _send_method
    self.channel_id, method_sig, args, content,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 221, in write_method
    write_frame(1, channel, payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 177, in write_frame
    frame_type, channel, size, payload, 0xce,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "testHello.py", line 16, in test_hello_aux
    print output.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 169, in get
    no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 155, in wait_for
    on_interval=on_interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 229, in consume
    no_ack=no_ack, accept=self.accept) as consumer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 359, in __init__
Process Process-3:
    self.revive(self.channel)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 371, in revive
    self.declare()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 381, in declare
    queue.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 504, in declare
    self.run()
    self.exchange.declare(nowait)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 166, in declare
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    nowait=nowait, passive=passive,
  File "testHello.py", line 16, in test_hello_aux
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 613, in exchange_declare
    print output.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 169, in get
    no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 155, in wait_for
    on_interval=on_interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 229, in consume
    no_ack=no_ack, accept=self.accept) as consumer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 359, in __init__
    self._send_method((40, 10), args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 56, in _send_method
    self.channel_id, method_sig, args, content,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 221, in write_method
    self.revive(self.channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 371, in revive
    self.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 381, in declare
    write_frame(1, channel, payload)
    queue.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/transport.py", line 177, in write_frame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 504, in declare
    frame_type, channel, size, payload, 0xce,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    self.exchange.declare(nowait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 166, in declare
    nowait=nowait, passive=passive,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 620, in exchange_declare
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    (40, 11),  # Channel.exchange_declare_ok
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 67, in wait
    self.channel_id, allowed_methods)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 237, in _wait_method
    self.method_reader.read_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/method_framing.py", line 189, in read_method
    raise m
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
Process Process-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "testHello.py", line 16, in test_hello_aux
    print output.get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 169, in get
    no_ack=no_ack,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 155, in wait_for
    on_interval=on_interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/backends/amqp.py", line 229, in consume
    no_ack=no_ack, accept=self.accept) as consumer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 359, in __init__
    self.revive(self.channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 371, in revive
    self.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 381, in declare
    queue.declare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 505, in declare
    self.queue_declare(nowait, passive=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/entity.py", line 531, in queue_declare
    nowait=nowait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/channel.py", line 1258, in queue_declare
    (50, 11),  # Channel.queue_declare_ok
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 67, in wait
    self.channel_id, allowed_methods)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 270, in _wait_method
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 69, in wait
    return self.dispatch_method(method_sig, args, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/abstract_channel.py", line 87, in dispatch_method
    return amqp_method(self, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqp/connection.py", line 526, in _close
    (class_id, method_id), ConnectionError)
UnexpectedFrame: Basic.publish: (505) UNEXPECTED_FRAME - expected content header for class 60, got non content header frame instead
```

celery --version 3.1.11 (Cipater)
amq --version 0.9.1

Comment: any code would be helpful

Comment: this problem is because I am publishing on the same channel from different processes. The channel is shared and probably rabbitmq receives interleaved messages.
I don't know how I can synchronize requests on the same channel.

Comment: AN issue s that channels are not thread safe. when you publish message with shared channel, your frames will be delivered out of order, and that's basically why you getting your error

Comment: Where can I find an example for my case? I use this call in celery

def test_hello_proc():
    procs = []
    for q in CLUSTERS:
 proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=test_hello_aux, args=(q, ))
 proc.start()
 procs.append(proc)

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

Answer (score 1):

When using Celery you should not need to use the python multiprocessing module. Celery takes care of everything for you.

Define your task in a file called tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Now assume the `add` function is actually what ever you would like to run in parallel. Let's also consider terms. Parallel means at the same time, while async means not synchronously. I cannot guarantee you tasks will be run at the same time, though I can guarantee they will not be run synchronously. For that reason, lets stick with the term async.

Celery has [Canvas](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#the-primitives), a set of primitives for async flow control. Two you would be interested in would be `group` and `chord`. `group` allows you to run a group of async tasks and ask block on the results of all of the async tasks (accomplishing what you were attempting with you join). `chord` provides the same functionality as `group` though fire a callback when all of the tasks complete.

An example of the calling code :

```
WAIT_TIME = 10 # how ever long you are willing to wait for your tasks

from tasks import add
from celery import group

future = group(add.s(i**i, i**i) for i in xrange(10))()
results = future.get(timeout=WAIT_TIME)
```

Celery tasks are automatically run in their own process (the workers you spawn) and do not require you to create further processes yourself.